# How to correctly define parameters for function of a Class loaded in runtime?

Tags: java, talend

I've created a Talend job that should be loaded in runtime. I'm loading job jar dynamically in code. After loading it, I need to invoke a function that will execute the job.

To performed it, I've followed the answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime) question. But when the function is invoked I'm getting `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`. I think the problem is in the function's parameters type definition, but I have troubles to define it correctly.

Here is my code:

```
String args[] = new String[7];
args[0] = "myParams";

File jobJar = new File("myjar.jar");
URL [] urls = new URL[1];
urls[0] = jobJar.toURI().toURL();

Class<?>[] params_type = new Class[]{args.getClass()}; //is it correct?

URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader(urls , this.getClass().getClassLoader());
Class classToLoad = Class.forName ("com.my.myTalendClass", true, child);
Method method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod ("runJobInTOS", params_type);
Object instance = classToLoad.newInstance();
Object result = method.invoke(instance,new Object[]{ args });
```

and the function `runJobInTOS` receives as parameters an array of Strings

Comment: If you know the class name and the method name, why are you using reflection?

Comment: Because the class of talend job is defined in the database and could be changed anytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use

```
Object result = method.invoke(instance,new Object[]{ args });
```

But not

```
Object result = method.invoke(instance,args);
```

In your code you pass a two-dimensional array to the method, not an ordinary array of Strings

Comment: passing parameters as you have proposed gives error of `wrong number of arguments`

Comment: have you posted any link to article?

Comment: http://yourmitra.wordpress.com/2008/09/26/using-java-reflection-to-invoke-a-method-with-array-parameters/ 
sorry

Comment: Thank you. This link was helpful! But I've also changed `args.getClass()` to `String[].getClass()`.. do not know what the difference.